# Which code fragment to use to handle USB device insertion?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usb

Applications can use the [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx) function to register to receive notification messages from the system. [This example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how to register for notification of events for the device interfaces which are members of the interface class whose GUID is passed to the function.

In this example which code fragment should I use to handle USB device insertion message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for **DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:** That is where USB device insertion message handled.

```
 case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
{
    //
    // This is the actual message from the interface via Windows messaging.
    // This code includes some additional decoding for this particular device type
    // and some common validation checks.
    //
    // Note that not all devices utilize these optional parameters in the same
    // way. Refer to the extended information for your particular device type 
    // specified by your GUID.
    //
    PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE b = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE) lParam;
    TCHAR strBuff[256];

    // Output some messages to the window.
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        msgCount++;
        StringCchPrintf(
            strBuff, 256, 
            TEXT("Message %d: DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL\n"), msgCount);
        break;
```